# How to define a recursive algebra for use in free applicative?

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative, scala-cats

I'm facing the problem of defining a recursive algebra to use with `FreeApplicative`.

Here is my failed attempt.
Let's assume we want the functionality to tag (groups of) effectful values.
I have inserted the dummy `Print` to have some constructor.

```
sealed trait Algebra[F[_],T]
case class Print[F[_]](s: String) extends Algebra[F,String]
case class Prefix[F[_],T](p: String, tagged: F[T]) extends Algebra[F,T]
```

When I try to define the free  type `FA` through (using [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector))

```
type FA[T] = FreeApplicative[Algebra[FA,?],T]
```

then the compiler complains with

> Error:(28, 38) illegal cyclic reference involving type FA
>       type FA[T] = FreeApplicative[Alg[FA,?], T]

How can I solve this problem?

I think when working with `Free` (monads), then the signature of `Prefix` could omit the reference to `tagged`. 
As monads chain their algebra calls, one could simply remember all prefix invocations on the executed path.
But with `Applicative` I do not see how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you mean `type FA[T] = FreeApplicative[Algebra[FA, ?],T]`? (This will still give you illegal cyclic reference, I'm just trying to clarify the problem.)

Comment: @Tomas You're right. I corrected the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the instructions of `Algebra` to refer to free programs that are themselves constructed using `Algebra`.

You will need to define your own "recursive" free applicative:

```
case class FreeApRec[F[_[_], _], A](fa: FreeApplicative[F[FreeApRec[F, ?], ?], A])
```

and implement the methods you need (this will be just forwarding to methods of `FreeApplicative` and wrapping the results).

[Here is the same done for the `Free` monad.](https://github.com/TomasMikula/nutcracker/blob/494e181fb411ed308b5f80b82a938b571c8da431/src/main/scala/nutcracker/util/FreeK.scala)

---

You could as well define the `FreeApRec` type above via a higher-kinded fixed-point operator, but the definition gets less transparent:

```
case class HFix[F[_[_], _], A](unfix: F[HFix[F, ?], A])

type FreeApRecF[F[_[_], _], K[_], A] = FreeApplicative[F[K, ?], A]

type FreeApRec[F[_[_], _], A] = HFix[FreeApRecF[F, ?[_], ?], A]
```

Comment: Ok, rolling my own free implementation was what I did in the last project I encountered this problem. To be more precise: I extended my algebra to cover the applicative cases. At least I can stop trying to make it work with existing `FreeApplicative`.

Comment: Since you have already implemented this. Do you encounter this problem often?

Comment: It's very subjective, but this problem came up already with my first attempt to use free monads. I would say it is inevitable if your DSL needs to support something analogous to higher-order functions (i.e. DSL programs manipulating other DSL programs).

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a solution, but rather another way to see why `FreeApplicative` doesn't do what you want, and also how to derive the
right signature mentioned in Tomas Mikula's answer.

The kind of `FreeApplicative[F, A]` is

```
(* -> *) -> * -> *
```

which essentially means that `FreeApplicative` takes a functor `F` of kind `* -> *` and builds another functor `FreeApplicative[F, ?]` again of kind `* -> *` from it.

However, your `Algebra` is not `* -> *` but rather something like

```
(* -> *) -> * -> *
```

and you want a "thing", say `FreeApRec` that builds a functor of kind `* -> *` from it, that is, `FreeApRec` should be something like

```
((* -> *) -> * -> *) -> * -> *
```

Now, this corresponds nicely to the signature that Tomas Mikula wrote down:

```
((* -> *) -> * -> *) -> * -> *
 \      /    |          |
  \    /     |          |
   \  /      |          |
   _[_]      _          |
 \                /     |
  \              /      |
   \            /       |
    \          /        |
     F[_[_], _]         A
 \                          /
  \                        /
   \                      /
    \                    /
    FreeApRec[F[_[_],_],A]
```

The standard `FreeApplicative` does not have this signature. If you call the "default category" of ordinary functions that everyone implicitly works with `C`, then `FreeApplicative` maps functors `[C, C]` to other functors `[C, C]`, but you want to take a `[[C,C] x C, C]` to `[C, C]`. That's again a category-theoretical-functor, but not an ordinary fp-`Functor`, because it has a different category as domain.

Comment: I somehow hoped that there was a way to partially apply the type constructor of the algebra. Like I tried with the cyclic reference. Maybe something involving `Fix`. I do understand your post, but I don't see how it "proofs" that it can't work.

Comment: @ziggystar It doesn't actually "prove" anything, to be honest, but rather vaguely hints at the fact that all the signatures don't seem to fit together, and that I don't see a way to build what you want from the pieces that you have... The standard `Fix[F[_]]` doesn't really seem to help either, because it is again `(* -> *) -> *`. What you want actually *is* exactly `Fix` of kind `(K -> K) -> K`, but not for `K = *`, but rather for `K = (* -> *)`. I *personally* usually ended up writing such fixpoint-functors from scratch for myself...

Comment: Right. I have seen this higher-kinded Fix called HFix: `type HFix[F[_[_], _], A] = F[HFix[F, ?], A]`. I added the definition using `HFix` to my answer.

Comment: @TomasMikula So it actually does work if you add three typedefs `HFix`, `FreeApRecF` and `FreeApRec`, without any additional classes, and the resulting thing actually implements `FreeApplicative`? I don't know, given that for any two categories one can always form a functor category `[C, D]` and then consider endofunctors on that, if one approached it systematically, one would need an infinite family of weirdly shaped `HHHHHHHHHHHFix`-functors. Too bad that functor categories are not first-class citizens in Scala... Anyone tried to implement this, though?

Comment: `HFix` in my answer is actually a class, to avoid illegal cyclic reference. And it implements the mentioned `FreeApRec`, in terms of `FreeApplicative`. To implement `FreeApplicative` itself, we would need even weirder fixed point operator, but I think it's possible. Unfortunately, we do need multiple shapes of fixed-point operators. Kind-polymorphism and partial application of type constructors would help in this regard, IMO.

Comment: @TomasMikula Yeah, that `type HFix` in your previous comment felt suspicious, it too generates illegal cyclic error... Kind-polymorphism: yes, but `AnyKind` feels kind of very restricted, but I would be thrilled to see if it can be used to compute fixed points in any functor category? `class Fix[F <: AnyKind](val unfix: F[Fix[F]])` doesn't seem to be valid (my dotty doesn't find `AnyKind` at all, should probably pull more bleeding edge version...). And even if it were: unclear where to put all the other type args in this construct.

Comment: Yeah, I'm unexcited about `AnyKind`.